# How can I compare same column value in a table?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
s|g
-+-
a|1
b|4
c|2
d|3
```

I want to add a new column, which indicates the average values in column g of other rows that have values that are greater than or equal to the current row. The resulting table looks like:

```
s|g|c
-+-+-
a|1|3    -> (4+2+3)/3 = 3
b|4|0    -> no rows are greater than 4 in g
c|2|3.5  -> (4+3)/2 = 3.5
d|3|4    -> (4)/1 = 4
```

How may I achieve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a self left join as the following:

```
SELECT T.s, T.g, COALESCE(AVG(D.g), 0) AS C
  FROM
tbl T LEFT JOIN tbl D
ON T.g<D.g
GROUP BY T.s, T.g
ORDER BY T.s
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/o6LylpGa).

Answer (score 0):

Use two correlated subqueries for that

Use an INDEX on `g` to make the query faster

```
  SELECT 
`s`, `g`
, COALESCE((SELECT SUM(`g`) FROM tab1 WHERE `g` > t1.`g`) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1 WHERE `g` > t1.`g`),0) gt
FROM tab1 t1
```

| s | g | gt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 3.0000 |
| b | 4 | 0.0000 |
| c | 2 | 3.5000 |
| d | 3 | 4.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2_mnsRR-)